# How to upload multiple files within a single request?

Tags: android, file-upload

i am trying to upload multiple files in single request. single file is uploading successfully but how to do in multiple case?

Here is for Single file upload ...

```
    public String uploadfile(String sourceFileUri) {

    String fileName = "";
    File file = null;
    String updatedFileName = "";

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    String HeyfileName = ""; 
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    // int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 5000000
    int maxBufferSize = 5000000;
    // File sourceFile = sourceFileUri;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File Does not exist");

    }
    File f = new File(sourceFileUri);        
      File files[] = f.listFiles();
      for (int i=0; i < files.length; i++) {                               
          // upload file here and when the fileUpload is complete the you save it to the array.. thats wat i think is best.. because you never know
          //Thread  or asynctask                         
      }

    System.out.println("Source file uri is " + sourceFileUri);
    if (sourceFileUri.contains(".pdf")) {
        fileName = sourceFileUri; /* +"default.jpg" */

        long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
        fileName = "file:///" + sourceFileUri;
        HeyfileName =    unixTime + ".pdf"; 


    } else { 
        MessageDialog.showMessage("Alert!", "Please upload only pdf file!",
                User_dashboard.this);

    }


    try {

        InputStream contentInputStream = getContentResolver()
                .openInputStream(Uri.parse(fileName));
        URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

        // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
        conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        // conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/pdf" +
        // boundary);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", HeyfileName);

        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"PDF_File\";filename=\""
                + HeyfileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        // dos.writeBytes
        // ("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadedfile";filename="" + selectedPath + """
        // + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        // create a buffer of maximum size
        bytesAvailable = contentInputStream.available();

        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // read file and write it into form...
        bytesRead = contentInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {

            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = contentInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = contentInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        }

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
        // Map<String, List<String>> response = conn.getRequestProperties();
        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        // serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseMessage();

        String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

        Log.i("uploadfile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage
                + ": " + serverResponseCode);

        if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

            /*
             * runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() {
             * 
             * String msg =
             * "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
             * +" http://demo.spearheadss.com/twerck/public/resource/image/"
             * +uploadFileName;
             * 
             * messageText.setText(msg); Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this,
             * "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); } });
             */
        }

        // close the streams //*/
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        String LogString = "";

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            LogString = LogString + inputLine;
        }
        responseServer = LogString.toString();
        // Log.i(Utils.TAG, LogString);
        // close streams
        contentInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

        pdialog.dismiss();
        ex.printStackTrace();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                Toast.makeText(User_dashboard.this,
                        "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in uploading: " + e);
        pdialog.dismiss();
        e.printStackTrace();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                Toast.makeText(User_dashboard.this,
                        "Uploading failed : please retry",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        Log.e("Upload file to server Exception",
                "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    try {

        inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        String str;

        while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {

            Log.e("Debug", "Server Response " + str);

        }

        inStream.close();

    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
    }
    pdialog.dismiss();
    return responseServer;

    // } // End else block
}
```

but i want to upload multiple files i have a list of files here

```
List<String> fileNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
fileNameList .add(file1);
fileNameList .add(file2);
fileNameList .add(file3);
```

assuming file name is as follows;

```
  file1 = "/sdcard/selected1.pdf";
  file2 = "/sdcard/selected1.pdf";
  file3 = "/sdcard/selected1.pdf";

this is giving me exception

InputStream contentInputStream = getContentResolver()
                .openInputStream(Uri.parse(myFiles.toString()));
```

now i am not getting how to pass fileNameList so that i can upload this.
is there any way?

Comment: You are sending one file between the lines new OutputStream() and serverResponseMessage. Just repeat for every file with a new InputStream. Can the server handle more files in one POST?

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have a sending class you could iterate through that list and pass one filename at time? Something like that comes to mind:

```
for (String fileName: fileNameList){ 
uploadFile(fileName);}
```

Comment: i want to post array not simple string using InputStream